# Adding 'Subscriptions' as default page in YouTube app

Tags: youtube

I use YouTube a lot in my phone, and specific in what I watch. I control this mainly using 'subscribing' channels what I really wanted to watch.

Now the problem is YouTube app has it's own default page called 'Home' which I totally hate it since it pollutes the feed by adding their own 'suggested' videos and I'm lost into videos that I wouldn't have watched otherwise.

Is there a way/app to set 'Subscription' page as the default?

Or is it possible to create a deep-link into my desktop so that that page opens directly !?

Or what are the better alternate to the official YouTube app ?

Comment: That might be possible: some launchers (e.g. Apex) offer to browse activities an app offers, and there are also stand-alone apps to do so (see [my answer here](/a/45634/16575). You then could create a shortcut to that activity (icon on the homescreen to launch directly into that activity).

Comment: Good idea @Izzy surprisingly Youtube has not listed that page as an activity.

Comment: That's nasty (but was worth a try). Afraid in this case chances are close to zero. Maybe trying an [alternative YT player](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_video_player#group_358)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&hl=en_US) app and created a new flow which I named "YouTube Launcher":

1. For the "Flow beginning" step, choose the option to "Install from home screen shortcut". Additionally, you can hide the official YouTube app from your app drawer so that you do not accidentally revert to old habits.
2. Add an "App Start" step and choose the YouTube app as the package.
3. Add a "Delay" step for 1 second.
4. Add an "Interact Touch" step and set the `Screen X0` value to 50% and the `Screen Y0` step to 90%. This step simulates tapping the subscriptions tab.

From there, each time to tap the new home screen shortcut the YouTube app will launch and automagically navigate to the Subscriptions tab.

Comment: I should try this for sure, so far I ended up using Kiwi browser with uBlock Origin, so that it blocks ads as well. And I added a homescreen shortcut directly to subscription page. Watching YT in browser is not that bad, and I get background play option for free.

Answer (score 1):

If you tap long on the Youtube shortcut icon, then some options are appear in a popup list including Subscriptions.
[image: Youtube options]

If you tap long on any of these options, then you can drag it and drop somewhere on your Home screen for make a shortcut for that.
You can use this trick for avoid the Home screen on your Youtube app, but it works with other apps too.

Note: it worked for me on Android 9 with Samsung One UI 1.0, but it could work on other versions too.

Comment: Just an additional note, the feature is known as "app shortcut" and should generally be available since Android 7.1.